# jQuery change values based on attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input class and I want to change it to select form attribute.

So far I have something similar that is working on my h2.title that change the word from Apple to Orange.

Example

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (){  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).live({
          mouseover: function(e) {
            $('h2.title').each(function() {
                var text = $(this).text();
                text = text.replace('Apple', 'Orange');
                $(this).text(text);         
            });
          }
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

And I really like this to be converted to select form attribute

```
<input class = "form-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng valid-maxlength" id="Banana" maxlength = "2000" name="Banana" type=text"
```

Is there a way to work about this? with 2 select options

Comment: format your code to let us read better

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this:

```
text = text.replace('Apple', $(this).attr("name"));
```

Here is a demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("mouseover", function(e) {
    $('h2.title').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      text = text.replace('Apple', $(this).attr("name"));
      $(this).text(text);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="title" name="Banana">Apple</h2>
<h2 class="title" name="Orange">Apple</h2>
<h2 class="title" name="Pineapple">Apple</h2>
<h2 class="title" name="Grape">Apple</h2>
```

Comment: For brevity I'd suggest a further move to: `$('h2.title').text(function(index, currentText) { return currentText.replace('Apple', this.name); });` the use of `each()` and multiple calls to the `text()` method, not to mention the use `$(this).attr('name')`, is doing far more work than necessary.

Comment: @DavidThomas Agreed on "brevity", but I left the code as is because it could be easier for the OP (i.e. personal coding style). As for "far more work", I don't see how your suggestion can do less work or have fewer calls to `text()`. Both my answer and your suggested code call `text()` twice, once to get the value and another to set it (although this is implicit in your code). And the `name` property as you suggested can only be used in `input` elements, not `h2`.